# compiled/installed kernel 3.5 in 12.04 usb keyboard/mouse not working at boot log on screen

Tags: 12.04, asus, multi-touch

I installed 12.04 on an Asus ep121 slate. Touch acts like a left mouse click. Multi-touch doesn't work. I calibrated the screen and installed the latest eGalax etouch driver-no joy. It booted to blank screen.

I reinstalled 12.104, then compiled and installed the latest stable kernel (3.5), in hopes that is better supports multi-touch or at least worked better with the eTouch driver. Rebooted. At log on screen, usb keyboard/mouse do not function.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Since 3.5 is worse than 3.2, I suggest you revert. Sorry...

Answer (score 0):

Try installing 12.04 making sure to check the "download updates while installing" option. Touchscreen seems to work fine for me then.

Comment: I applied the latest update yesterday (3.27 kernel). It is working now. I don't have all of the mutlti-touch features, but I can scroll, launch apps and open windows. I just have to figure out how to get the on-screen keyboard to appear when I need to type (such as entering URL in Firefox). The only time it comes up is when the screen locks and I have to enter my password.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing from PPA instead. It worked for me with asus eeepc.

http://www.howopensource.com/2012/07/how-to-install-linux-kernel-3-5-quantal-in-ubuntu-12-04-11-10-11-04-10-10-and-10-04/